# Restar varias veces al aplastar un boton sin usar un ciclo en java

Tags: java, condiciones

tengo confusión sobre como realizar este ejercicio en java, tengo mi saldo inicial que es de $1 y al momento de aplastar un boton debe restarme 0.08 ctvs y mostrarme mensaje enviado y así debe ser hasta que mi saldo sea menor que 0.08ctvs y me imprima saldo insuficiente, intente de esta manera pero no me funciona

```
    Double saldo = 1;
    Double calcular_saldo;
    
    calcular_saldo = saldo - 
    0.08;

    If(calcular_saldo>0.08){
    System.out.println("mensaje enviado");
} else {
   System.out.println("saldo insuficiente");
```

Esto me sirve para restar los 0.08 ctvs una sola vez, al momento de aplastar el botón de nuevo no me vuelve a restar con el valor ya obtenido con anterioridad, probe con -= en la operación y tampoco funcionó, el requisito era hacerlo sin contadores y en la condición solo me aparece una vez igualmente, agradezco sus consejos y observaciones, es un ejercicio con planteamiento sencillo pero me estoy confundiendo en como hacer que se siga restando y me imprima el mensaje

Comment: Creo que debes restar `saldo` en vez de `cacular_saldo` . O complovar el saldo y despues reasignar la variable saldo: `if(calcular_saldo>0.08){saldo=calcular_saldo;}`

Answer (score 1):

Tu código actual tiene varios problemas:

- declaras e inicializas la variable saldo cada vez que se presiona el botón... de esta manera siempre estas restando el valor a 1.00, que es el valor recién asignado a la nueva variable
- esta variable, al estar declarada dentro de la rutina, deja de existir cuando termina la ejecución de esta, que es su ámbito
- Aunque la variable saldo existiera luego de terminar la rutina, nunca le asignas el nuevo saldo, por lo que tampoco variaría del `1.0` original. De hecho, yo haría el cálculo directo sobre el saldo, de manera que la variable adicional `calcular_saldo` resulta innecesaria.

Así que, la solución es:

- realizar la declaración e inicialización de la variable saldo en otro lugar, para que almacene el valor que queda después de que haya terminado cada ejecución de la rutina que le resta el saldo.
- asegurarse que esta variable va almacenando el saldo que queda luego de cada ejecución

Una posible solución es declarar `saldo` como miembro de la clase, dónde podemos inicializarla de una vez. Aprovecho para escribir una rutina especializada en hacer la tarea, que puedes invocar desde el manejador de evento del botón.

```
public class so434262 {

    private Double saldo = 1.0;

    private void restarSaldo() {
        if (saldo >= 0.08) {
            saldo = saldo - 0.08;
            System.out.println("mensaje enviado");
        } else {
            System.out.println("saldo insuficiente");
        }
    }
```

Ahora, sustituye el código que tienes allí por una llamada a `restarSaldo()` y debieras obtener una salida como esta:

```
run-single:
mensaje enviado
mensaje enviado
mensaje enviado
mensaje enviado
mensaje enviado
mensaje enviado
mensaje enviado
mensaje enviado
mensaje enviado
mensaje enviado
mensaje enviado
mensaje enviado
saldo insuficiente
saldo insuficiente
saldo insuficiente
saldo insuficiente
saldo insuficiente
```

Comment: Jeje. Derecho de author.